# Deploy react js + django + CentOS + SSL

Tags: reactjs, django, ssl, centos8

I need some help deploying react js + django + CentOS + SSL.

Here's what I have:

**react-ui/src/config/constant.js**

```
 BACKEND_SERVER = "http://mysite.mydomain.xxx:8000/api/";
```

**react-ui/package.json**

```
 "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
 "build": "HTTPS=true react-scripts build",
```

**react-ui/.env**

```
HTTPS=true
```

yarn start

**django**

I know some of these are high risk entries, but I am working on getting this functional.

```
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '*' ]
    CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True
    # Load the default ones
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["https://localhost:3000", "https://mysite.mydomain.xxx:3000"]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://localhost:3000", "https://mysite.mydomain.xxx:3000"]
   
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True
```

**run django**

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
  upstream mysite_server {
      server unix:/home/myuser/mysite/django-api/mysite.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.mydomain.xxx;

    #location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    #location /static/ {
    #    root /home/myuser/mysite/django-api;
    #}

#location / {
#        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuser/mysite/django-api/mysite.sock;
#    }

    return 301 https://mysite.mydomain.xxx$request_uri;

}
    
     server {
            listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
            listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name  mysite.mydomain.xxx;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
            ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/tls/private/star-yyy-xxx.bag";
            ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/tls/private/star-yyy-xxx.bag";
    #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
    #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
            ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
            ssl_session_timeout  10m;
            ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #
    #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
            include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    #
            location / {
    
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # <-
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    
    
            }
    #
            error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
            }
    #
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
            }
        }

    sudo service nginx start
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=myusergroup
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/mysite/django-api
ExecStart=/home/myuser/.local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myuser/mysite/django-api/mysite.sock core.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo systemctl start gunicorn

sudo service httpd stop
```

What am I missing?
Why doesn't this work?